# Gerard Butler in the Watchmen?

Tags: watchmen, casting

I was watching *Watchmen: The Ultimate Cut* this evening. I'd seen the original back in the theater when it came out. During the opening credits I happened to see Gerard Butler's name come across the screen:

[image]

Not remembering him in the movie, I look to IMDB.com to figure out who he was in the movie, yet I don't find him there. I also looked on his credits and don't find the Watchmen there. Also, looking through the end credits, I don't see him listed there, either.

***What gives?***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found in the IMDB [trivia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409459/trivia):

> Zack Snyder wanted to cast his 300 (2006) star Gerard Butler in this film and even promised him a role. When all the roles were cast and Butler didn't have one, Snyder cast him in Tales of the Black Freighter (2009), which is based on the comic-within-a-comic from the Watchmen graphic novel and was released on DVD around the time Watchmen was released in theaters.

So Gerard appeared in [TotBF](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1295071/), which is shown throughout the movie. More info [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7661/what-is-the-significance-of-tales-of-the-black-freighter).

Comment: [Gerard Butler Talks Black Freighter](https://www.empireonline.com/movies/news/gerard-butler-talks-black-freighter/)

Comment: As I have never seen the theatrical or 'The Ultimate Cut' (as I was satisfied enough with 'The Directors Cut' and have to date believed that it is well paced enough despite its running length and may suffer from the extra, complimentary, content) the shot of the Enola Gay on my copy only has Malin Akerman's name overlaid which may explain why he was not acknowledged on IMDB.